# Should the metal frame on a Nokia 3310/5110 style LCD display be grounded?

Tags: grounding, lcd

I'm currently tinkering with a design which includes a Nokia 3310/5110 style LCD, and I've noticed that the prototyping boards don't seem to connect the metal frame to ground:

[image: Example A]

There are pads, but there seems to be a very healthy gap between them and anything else such as the ground plane; they appear to be just for mechanical fixing.  Is there a reason that the frame retaining a LCD should *not* be grounded?

Comment: There’s gnd and there’s gnd. Which one? Chassis gnd (assuming a metallic enclosure)?  The method of grounding comes into play when considering ESD.

Comment: If you think ESD is an issue, use ESD technique of a high-value resistor between one of those frame pads and Gnd. Those electrical contact points between frame tabs and PCB pads seems tenuous - those on the left side look like they make no contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the docs: https://www.makerfabs.com/desfile/files/Nokia5510LCD.pdf
You'll see that metal case isn't mentioned at all, it simply isn't relevant for the COG. There is no requirement for it.
In practice this means that it should be left disconnected, and that way prevent human-generated ESD from reaching COG through metal casing.